# What does the pointer 'this+1' refer to in C++?

Tags: c++

I was wandering through the code of [Sequitur G2P](https://www-i6.informatik.rwth-aachen.de/web/Software/g2p.html) and found a really strange line of code:

```
public:
    ...
    const Node *childrenEnd() const { return (this+1)->finalized.firstChild_; }
```

I know that `this` is a pointer to the current object, and since it is a pointer, the operation is perfectly legal, but what does `this+1` actually refer to?

Comment: One of the problems of C++, and reason smart pointers were added to the standard library, was that raw pointers had too many roles. Both as iterators and as owning handles. This code snippet however seems to relish in this ambiguity and its abuse.

Comment: It's only ever used here `return binarySearch(childrenBegin(), childrenEnd() - 1, t);` with `-1` does that make a difference?

Comment: @JeffUK No it doesn't, if `this+1` is pointed to something different but still try to dereference with `->finalized` then it crash right away

Comment: This code hurts my eyes. I hope this is called in a very controlled environment.

Comment: I don't think the new title is appropriate, `this+1` is not an increment, `this++` is. Obviously, you cannot reassign the value of `this` in C++. I came back to this question confused by the non sense of the title thinking it was another question.

Comment: @Winter You are right

Comment: It is a dirty way to get what you want.  It assumes the object lies in an array and it is not the last element.  And that the children are also contiguous so that the first child of the next object marks the end of this object's children.  With these assumptions the code says "this object's children end where the next object's children start".  `this+1` refers to the next object.

Comment: This being said, the meaning of `this+1` would be a good question for a test.  To see if you have understood pointers in C++.

Comment: @FlorianF I really don't think this would be a good question for a test.

Comment: @PCLuddite: Actually I was thinking of a job interview.  To see if you can make some sense out of it.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Presumably `this` is part of an array, so `this+1` would refer to the next object in that array.

Comment: then isn't this operation extremely risky? since there is no guarantee that this object comes in a array or the next object belongs to the same class

Comment: @AtheS21 Well, you have to guarantee yourself that the next object is in contiguous memory with the correct alignment, and is of a compatible type.

Comment: It would risk running off the end of the array, yes. Maybe the author does the proper checking, maybe not. Maybe it's part of a larger object and you are guaranteed to have a next object, don't know.

Comment: But this is definitely UB for the last object.Right?

Comment: No, just doing `this + 1` is not UB. Dereferencing the result with `->finalized` is though.

Comment: @AtheS21: C++ arrays are homogeneous. If there's a next element, it has the same type. It's only the "no next element" that forms a risk.

Comment: It's actually part of a `std:vector<>` not part of a C-style array, but the standard guarantees contiguous memory for these too. This bit of code is part of a private implementation class, and is actually only called from one place. The construction of the objects guarantees that it is safe.

Comment: @MSalters I don't think homogeneity is enough to avoid what AtheS21 brings up.  Consider a homogeneous array of a Derived type, while the function evaluating `(this+1)` is a function on a Base type which is smaller than Derived.  That being said, this is C++.  Half the fun is being able to make insane optimizations by leveraging the a-priori information a developer has!

Comment: My opinion is that it's a programming contractual construct. That is to say, legal due to the developer writing it in a way that internally it avoids invoking UB. And it is up to the user to not violate that contract using the data in an unspecified or otherwise incorrect manner.

Comment: @AtheS21 "then isn't this operation extremely risky? since there is no guarantee that this object comes in a array or the next object belongs to the same class"  That is the nature of C/C++ and an unchecked language.  You can do some very powerful things without restrictions, and pay the price when you do it wrong.

Comment: Whether any object is or isn't an element of an array is just a question of syntax, and by using a pointer we eliminate the distinction altogether. It's always legal to increment a pointer that points to an object.

Answer (score 34):

`this` is simply a pointer which refers to *this* object. Since it's a pointer, you can apply pointer arithmetic and even array indexing.

If *this* object is an element in an array, `this+1` would point to the next object in the array.

If it's not, well it's just going to treat whatever is at that memory the same as *this* object, which will be undefined behaviour unless it is the same type.

Comment: Yeah, I see the problem, however since this is the code of a pretty well-known tool in NLP, I thought there must be a good reason to do so. This is the first time I've seen code like this

Comment: It's only UB if the result is dereferenced.

Comment: "If it's not (some definitive statement)" No, Undefined Behaviour is Undefined. It could do *anything*. If the compiler can prove you always go off the end it can emit an empty program, or one that formats your hd or whatever it wants

Comment: @Caleth the standard doesn't say it's UB to read off the end of an array, just that it might be . It's intentionally (and annoyingly) vague on this purpose

Comment: @M.M: Lack of defined behavior is also undefined behavior. The C++ standard doesn't enumerate all undefined behavior. (C does, IIRC, in an appendix).

Comment: It's defined that if a pointer points to something of the right type then dereferencing it is fine. If you increment off the end of an array but happen to end up pointing to the right thing, then there's no UB in deferencing.

Comment: @M.M That's wrong.  If you dereference a pointer which points one beyond the end of an array, you have UB.  (If that pointer happens to compare equal to the address of another object of the same type, you probably won't get a crash, but you still have UB - except I can't find chapter and verse for that.)

Comment: @M.M The thing is how would you know what stands next to the end of an array? We don't know and still try to dereference it, it might work, or crash, isn't that just how UB essentially is?

Comment: @AtheS21 No, UB is deeper than this. It controls the optimisations available to the compiler; if something is UB, the compiler can treat it as "this will never happen", and optimise accordingly, including (as Caleth noted) changing your whole program to `return 1` or whatever. For example, if you dereference a pointer and follow that with a null-check of the same pointer, the compiler will conclude that the block of code will never execute, since the pointer cannot possibly be null, since you tried to dereference it. But if the dereference is optimised away, you get no run-time error :)

Comment: @AtheS21 Sometimes you could know what's there, e.g. if we're in a struct and have verified there's no padding.

Comment: @M.M If you called this function in a `for` loop, the compiler could remove the loop-end condition, since before the loop is ended, you get UB. Does not seem too far fetched if the method gets inlined before optimization.

Answer (score 5):

As it is NLP it makes sense to optimize memory management. I assume you find overloaded new/delete methods as well.

The this+1 construct assumes all objects reside in an array. The name 'childrenEnd' of the method indicates it returns a pointer to an address of the end of the children of the current node.

Thus you are looking at an implementation of a tree structure. All siblings are adjacent and their children as well.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there is a case, when this thing could be used. I don't recommend to use this method, but it certainly works.

I believe, in NLP code it was used something like that:

when you want your object to behave as a collection (an array etc) to use it similarly as an array with something range-based etc, you can do this trick:

```
struct Obj {
...
Obj* begin() { return this; }
Obj* end() { return this+1; }
...
}
```

Now, you can use this object in, for example, range-based for-loops...
Sometimes all that is necessary... but just even there you'd better use "nullptr" or even do refactoring than to use this trick.

Answer (score 0):

"this + 1" in C++ class means:

if the "this" object is a member of another object it will point to the address of the parent's object next variable declared just after the "this" object variable:

Example:

```
class B
{
public:
    void* data()
    {
        return this + 1;
    }
};

class A
{
public:
    B m_b;
    char m_test;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    A a;
    a.m_test = 'H';

    void* p = a.m_b.data();
    char c;

    memcpy(&c, p, sizeof(char));
    return 0;
}
```

c is equal 'H'.

Long story short it allows to access to parent's class data without passing parent's pointer to the child class. In this example this + 1 point to the m_test member of the class A.