# Use-case and behavior of `this[i]`

Tags: c++, this

I want to know what is the use scope of `this[i]`. I know this is clearly an useless question but let say it for science. What are the behaviors allow by the standard for indexing `this` ? I didn't find information about it, [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/this).

---

Stupid example:

```
#include <iostream>

class foo {
public:
  int value;
  void bar(std::size_t size, int a) {
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      this[i].value = a--;
    }
  }
};

int main() {
  foo foos[42];
  (*foos).bar(sizeof foos / sizeof *foos, 42);
  for (auto &foo : foos) {
    std::cout << foo.value << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

---

Is it only allow with array ? Maybe. What about heritage ? I think it's undefined behavior. Do you know some use-case ? It's just some questions about `this[i]`, don't answer to these directly if you don't want to.

Comment: relevant though less general: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45340891/what-does-the-pointer-this1-refer-to-in-c

Comment: AFAIK `this[i]` is the same as `*(this + i)`. This should be ok as long as i doesn't exceed the boundaries of the array. For a single object the code should also be ok as long as `size` is `0`. But why would you write such a monstrosity?

Comment: `(*foos).bar` is commonly written as `foos->bar`.

Comment: @SimonKraemer You don't want to know... one friend send me code from his Korean teammate ;). When I saw their use of `this[i]` (by the way their code is clearly wrong, out of bound everywhere ;)), I just asking myself what could be the use-case.

Comment: @nwp - in this case, it might be more common to write it as `foos[0].bar`, since `foos` is actually an array.

Comment: @Stargateur - the code you have is probably less of a "use case" than it is code written by someone who doesn't properly understand usage of pointers in C++.

Answer (score 8):

`this` is just a pointer. The `ptr[n]` syntax is identical to `*(ptr + n)`.

> Do you know some use-case ?

No, there's no valid reason to use `this[n]`. The class itself shouldn't assume that the current instance is part of an array or that there are other instances close by in contiguous memory.

Design the class in such a way that it will work independently of where/how it is instantiated.

---

Your code can be modernized/improved significantly.

1. Use `std::array` instead of C-style arrays.
2. Don't do manual pointer arithmetic.
3. Have `foo` only deal with the current instance.
4. Do not use `endl` unless you want to flush the `cout` buffer. Use `\n` instead.

```
class foo {
public:
  int value;
  void bar(int a) {
    this->value -= a;
  }
};

int main() {
  std::array<foo, 42> foos;
  for (auto &foo : foos) {
    foo.bar(1);
    std::cout << foo.value << '\n';
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Clang uses this in places to emulate flexible array members in C++.

Comment: @TartanLlama I'm curious to see how they go about it, do you have a link perchance?

Comment: "Your code can be modernized significantly.", it's clearly not the point of my question, by the way, your code don't have the same behavior of mine.

Comment: @Stargateur: I know it's not the point of your question. It's just extra advice.

Comment: They do the flexible array thing [here](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/master/lib/CodeGen/CGCleanup.h#L152) and pointer arithmetic assuming layout [here](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/master/include/clang/AST/Type.h#L3644). Both of those are used in some other places as well. (I know it's `this+n` instead of `this[n]`, but it's essentially equivalent).

Comment: @TartanLlama It's strange clang handle FMA extension in c++.

Comment: afaik 3 and 4 are not about modernization but it was never a good idea to use `this[i]` and `endl` always did more than end a line